# Django: And conditional in Case

Tags: django

I want to do something like this:

```
all_objects.annotate(c=Count(
                             Case(
                             When(hit__question=A AND                                 
                                  hit__participant=B, then=1 )
```

How would i go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `When` object can behave just like a normal `.filter` so we just need to add the different field lookups as separate arguments like so:

```py
all_objects.annotate(c=Count(
                             Case(
                             When(hit__question=A,                                
                                  hit__participant=B, then=1 )
                             # rest of query
```

Comment: Deceptively simple. Perfect.